# html mail sending error in mailR in R

Tags: r

Looking for solution of this error in sending mail through mailR packages,.
When I'm sending normal text mail, its being sent normally but when its for html, saved in a location, its failed with mentioned error.

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential
552-5.7.0 security issue. Please visit
552-5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BlockedMessage to review our
552 5.7.0 message content and attachment content guidelines. k10-v6sm26095359pfj.29 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2202)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1980)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1197)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

I search arround for solution of this but failed yet, updated code of mailR also tested from gethub page but still its failed.

Regards
Vishan